# TypeScript: is there a way to convert the union type of strings to an enum

Tags: typescript

is there a way to convert the union type of strings to an `enum`? e.g

```
type SomeType = 'A' | 'B' | 'C'
```

is there way to generate an enum based on it so we get

```
enum SomeTypeEnum {
  'A' = 'A',
  'B' = 'B',
  'C' = 'C'
}
```

Comment: Nope, types are not emitted, but enums are.

Comment: If you control the type creation, you can go the other way around - create a const/ enum and query its keys/ values type https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAyiAtgUwCoE8AOyCiYCuiMAvDAN4BQMMA5AII0wBcNAhjQDRW0BCjLAI07caAYX41gNCgF8YrCDFCQoAbgoUoWZPCRptJGFuwgAZrpQZseQgG0A1snRmj2lwkvabiALqqYAPQBMABurAA2+MgQmgYe+tgA0k6KpI7O5sbI7npWuASI-kEw6TFAA